# Kobold2D Device Orientation

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, screen-orientation, kobold2d

I'm curious if anyone has figured this out. As of iOS 6 there's been a change in how the device orientation works. As far as I know, the new method looks like this:

```
-(BOOL) shouldAutorotate {

UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationUnknown)
    orientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;

if (orientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
    // do some stuff
}
return NO;
}
```

My question is, in Kobold2D, where do I put this method so that it will be called to prevent the orientation from changing? I can't seem to get the device to stop re-orienting no matter what I do.

Comment: it goes in AppDelegate.m

Comment: Ah, just the guy I was hoping would answer. If I put this in AppDelegate.m, it doesn't seem to be called when the device rotates. Also, it doesn't stop KKInput from providing translations according to the device's orientation. I.E. when I go to landscape mode, a horizontal pan across the screen to the right (from camera to home button) will produce a translation like (3.55, 0.0), instead of the expected (0.0, -3.55).